# When using document.location and redirecting using header :location goes into infinite loop in php but not when using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am trying to redirect user to a different page after he clicks the delete button:-

So what happens is in the table if he clicks the delete button

```
if ($column_name1 === "DLT")
                                     echo '<td class=center><a href=javascript:confirmDelete("#data/del.php?id=' . $res1[$i]['ID']  .'")></a></td>';<script>
        function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
       document.location = delUrl;
      }
    }
    </script>
```

so it basically goes to that URL which calls del.php script which deletes the row corresponding to that ID.

// A snippet of DEL.php

```
$qry = $report[$choice];

$stmt = oci_parse($connection,$qry);
$r=oci_execute($stmt);

if ($r) {
            header( 'Location: http://localhost:8080/index.php#data/test1.php?param=10&edit=1' ) ;
        }
```

when I used the HEADER(' Location: ') for redirecting to a different page in DEL.php it went into an infinite loop redirecting back to del.php

but when I used

```
if ($r) {
            echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/index.php#data/test1.php?param=10&edit=1'</script>" ;
        }
```

This work just fine .. .Why is that .. I am not able to comprehend?

Also if

```
if ($r) {
include('abc.php');
func_in_abc(1);                
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/index.php#data/test1.php?param=10&edit=1'</script>" ;
            }
```

So calling this abc.php puts it into a loop again and it never redirects to the page I want??

Comment: GET request for a deletion, that is a bad idea.

Comment: A debug tip: Check your server access log - what request does the server see it as? `http://localhost:8080/index.php` or `http://localhost:8080/index.php#data/test1.php` ? Also, running firebug or chrome developer tools and network tab shall show you what response headers the server actually sent.

Comment: @LordLoh If I use the header:location redirect it redirects to the same del.php page in a loop

Comment: @epascarello How do I do it via POST